# Help with GDI+ interop in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, interop, gdi+

I'm using some code to enable me to render rotated text with the TextRenderer.DrawText method. (By default, DrawText can only copy a straight forward x and y transform from a graphics object).

The code (C#) is from: [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/116051/rotated-text-is-no-longer-rendered-using-the-textrenderer-class). See below for a VB conversion.

The code takes a graphics object, creates a device context and copies the transform matrix from the graphics object. It works, but I'd like, also, to set the TextRenderingHint, so I tried:

```
<DllImport("gdiplus.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
Public Shared Function GdipSetTextRenderingHint(ByVal graphics As HandleRef, ByVal textRenderingHint As System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint) As Integer
End Function
```

And then after the SetClip statement, I place: GdipSetTextRenderingHint(hDC, someHint)

This gives me a memory access violation error, so I think I should be using something other than hDC as the argument.

I can get it to work by creating the device context from the original graphics object, and then creating another graphics object from the device context. I then set the hint on the new graphics object. This seems a bit convoluted so I was wondering if it was possible through interop.

**VB.Net code conversion:**

```
Friend Class TextRendererDC
    Implements IDeviceContext
    Implements IDisposable

    Private graphics As Graphics
    Private dc As IntPtr

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal g As Graphics)
        Me.graphics = g
    End Sub

    Public Function GetHdc() As IntPtr Implements System.Drawing.IDeviceContext.GetHdc

        Dim xform As NativeMethods.XFORM
        Dim clipRgn As IntPtr

        Using transf As Matrix = Me.graphics.Transform
            xform = New NativeMethods.XFORM(transf)
        End Using

        Using clip As Region = Me.graphics.Clip
            clipRgn = clip.GetHrgn(Me.graphics)
        End Using

        Me.dc = Me.graphics.GetHdc()

        Dim hDC As New HandleRef(Me, Me.dc)
        Dim hRegion As New HandleRef(Nothing, clipRgn)

        SetTransform(hDC, xform)
        SetClip(hDC, hRegion)
        // The below call creates a memory access violation.
        NativeMethods.GdipSetTextRenderingHint(hDC, System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit)

        Return Me.dc
    End Function

    Public Sub ReleaseHdc() Implements System.Drawing.IDeviceContext.ReleaseHdc
        If Me.dc <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Me.graphics.ReleaseHdc()
            Me.dc = IntPtr.Zero
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose
        ReleaseHdc()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub SetTransform(ByVal hdc As HandleRef, ByVal xform As NativeMethods.XFORM)
        NativeMethods.SetGraphicsMode(hdc, NativeMethods.GM_ADVANCED)
        NativeMethods.SetWorldTransform(hdc, xform)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub SetClip(ByVal hdc As HandleRef, ByVal hRegion As HandleRef)
        NativeMethods.SelectClipRgn(hdc, hRegion)
    End Sub

    Private Class NativeMethods

        Public Const GM_ADVANCED As Integer = 2

        <DllImport("Gdi32")> _
        Public Shared Function SetGraphicsMode(ByVal hdc As HandleRef, ByVal mode As Integer) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("Gdi32")> _
        Public Shared Function SetWorldTransform(ByVal hDC As HandleRef, ByVal xform As NativeMethods.XFORM) As Boolean
        End Function

        <DllImport("Gdi32")> _
        Public Shared Function SelectClipRgn(ByVal hDC As HandleRef, ByVal hRgn As HandleRef) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("gdiplus.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)> _
        Public Shared Function GdipSetTextRenderingHint(ByVal graphics As HandleRef, ByVal textRenderingHint As System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint) As Integer
        End Function

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
        Public Class XFORM

            Public eM11 As Single
            Public eM12 As Single
            Public eM21 As Single
            Public eM22 As Single
            Public eDx As Single
            Public eDy As Single

            Public Sub New()
                Me.eM11 = 1.0!
                Me.eM22 = 1.0!
            End Sub

            Public Sub New(ByVal transform As Matrix)
                Me.eM11 = 1.0!
                Me.eM22 = 1.0!
                Me.eM11 = transform.Elements(0)
                Me.eM12 = transform.Elements(1)
                Me.eM21 = transform.Elements(2)
                Me.eM22 = transform.Elements(3)
                Me.eDx = transform.Elements(4)
                Me.eDy = transform.Elements(5)
            End Sub

        End Class

    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that fits the "a little knowledge could be dangerous" mold.  Not even the native C++ programmers call the gdiplus entry point directly, they use the C++ wrapper in `<gdiplus.h>`

The failure mode here is that your program is loading the *wrong* version of gdiplus.dll, the one in c:\windows\system32.  The legacy version.  The right one is in the Windows side-by-side cache, .NET's System.Drawing assembly contains code to make sure it gets the right version of the DLL from the cache.

Not the one you get.  Yours isn't even initialized, GdiplusStartup was never called.  Kaboom.

No clue what you're trying to accomplish.  The Graphics class has a TextRenderingHint property, no need for the killer poke.

Comment: Well I've never seen anything like that before when I've done interop. I see the shared sub New in GDip which calls initialize to load the library. I would have assumed the correct lib would be automatically picked up. Anyway, as to why I'm doing it, when TexterRendererDC is created, it copies the transform matrix and clip from the supplied graphics object - nothing else. Its a moot point now anyway as the DrawText method tries to cast the device context to a graphics in order to get at the rendering hint. Therefore, my convoluted solution, at the end of my question, is the only way to go.